# initializer_list<const T> to vector<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, initializer-list, auto

I've got the following code that builds in VS but it doesn't make it through the gcc compiler.

```
void test(const std::vector<double>&);

const auto v = { 1., 2. };
test(v);
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af041f50edee027f

Is gcc right, is there a problem with this code? Removing const in front of auto fixes the problem.

Comment: [clang is with VCC on this one](https://godbolt.org/g/0CBszd).

Comment: This is a known GCC bug.